# Compare fields in two files taking closest match

Tags: bash, sed, awk, computational-geometry

I am trying to resolve locations in lat and long in one file to a couple of named fields in another file.

I have one file that is like this..

```
                 f1--f2--f3--------f4--------                f5---
 R               20175155 41273951N078593973W                18012              
 R               20175156 41274168N078593975W                18000              
 R               20175157 41274387N078593976W                17999              
 R               20175158 41274603N078593977W                18024              
 R               20175159 41274823N078593978W                18087
```

Each character is in a specific place so I need to define fields based on characters.

f1 char 18-21; f2 char 22 - 25; f3 char 26-35; f4 char 36-45; f5 char 62-66.

I have another much larger csv file that has fields 11, 12, and 13 to correspond to f3, f4, f5.

```
awk -F',' '{print $11, $12, $13}'
41.46703821 -078.98476926 519.21
41.46763555 -078.98477791 524.13
41.46824123 -078.98479015 526.67
41.46884129 -078.98480615 528.66
41.46943371 -078.98478482 530.50
```

I need to find the closest match to file 1 field 1 && 2 in file 2 field 11 && 12;

When the closest match is found I need to insert field 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 from file 1 into file 2 field 16, 17, 18, 19, 20.

As you can see the format is slightly different. File 1 breaks down like this..

File 1

```
f3-------f4--------

DDMMSSdd DDDMMSSdd 

41273951N078593973W
```

File 2

```
f11-------- f12---------

DD dddddddd  DDD dddddddd

41.46703821 -078.98476926
```

N means f3 is a positive number, W means f4 is a negative number.

I changed file 1 with sed, ridiculous one liner that works great.. **(better way???)**

```
cat $file1 |sed 's/.\{17\}//' |sed 's/\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{9\}\)\(.\)\(.\{9\}\)\(.\)\(.\{16\}\)\(.\{5\}\)/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8/'|sed 's/\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.*\)/\1\2,\3,\4.\5\6\7,\8\9/'|sed 's/\(.\{31\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.*\)/\1,\2.\3/'
```

2017,5155, 41,27,39.51,N,078,59,39.73,W,18012
2017,5156, 41,27,41.68,N,078,59,39.75,W,18000
2017,5157, 41,27,43.87,N,078,59,39.76,W,17999
2017,5158, 41,27,46.03,N,078,59,39.77,W,18024
2017,5159, 41,27,48.23,N,078,59,39.78,W,18087

Now I have to convert the formats.. **(RESOLVED this (see below)--problem -- The numbers are rounded off too far. I need to have at least six decimal places.)**

```
awk -F',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i <= 2) printf ($i","); else if (i == 3&&$6 == "S") printf("-"$3+($4/60)+($5/3600)","); else if (i == 3&&$6 == "N") printf($3+($4/60)+($5/3600)","); else if (i == 7&&$10 == "W") printf("-"$7+($8/60)+($9/3600)","); else if (i == 7&&$10 == "E") printf($7+($8/60)+($9/3600)","); if (i == 11) printf ($i"\n")}}'
```

2017,5155,41.461,-78.9944,18012
2017,5156,41.4616,-78.9944,18000
2017,5157,41.4622,-78.9944,17999
2017,5158,41.4628,-78.9944,18024
2017,5159,41.4634,-78.9944,18087

That's where I'm at.

**RESOLVED THIS**
**I need to get the number format to have at least 6 decimal places from this formula.**

**printf($3+($4/60)+($5/3600))**
Added "%.8f"

**printf("%.8f", $3+($4/60)+($5/3600))**

Next issue will be to **match the fields file 1 f3 and f4 to the closest match in file 2 f11 and f12.**

Any ideas?

Then I will need to calculate the distance between the fields.

In Excel the formuls would be like this..

```
=ATAN2(COS(lat1)*SIN(lat2)-SIN(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1), SIN(lon2-lon1)*COS(lat2))
```

**What could I use for that calculation?**

****UPDATE---
I am looking at a short distance for the matching locations. I was thinking about applying something simple like Pythagoras’ theorem for the nearest match. Maybe even use less decimal places. It's got to be many times faster.
maybe something like this..****

```
x = (lon2-lon1) * Math.cos((lat1+lat2)/2);

y = (lat2-lat1);

d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
```

Then I could do the heavy calculations required for greater accuracy after the final file is updated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can get the precision you require with `awk`.  However, `bc` should offer "arbitrary precision" as well as a good library of geometric functions.  I suggest you split the question into "how do I normalize these two file formats" and "how do I calculate with `bc` when the numbers are in a file".  Maybe you can already solve both questions on your own.

Comment: Maybe this post can help: http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/work-shell-calculating-distance-between-two-latitudelongitude-points

Comment: @tripleee: See the `OFMT` and `CONVFMT` variables in AWK. You can't get arbitrary precision like `bc` has, but you can certainly get enough decimal places for this application.

Comment: If you're using GNU AWK (`gawk`), you can use the `FIELDWIDTH` variable to split records that consist of fixed width fields. You could also use the `substr()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do the distance calculation after you perform the closest match: closest is defined by comparison of the distance values. Awk can evaluate the formula that you want (looks like great-circle distance?). Take a look at [this chapter](http://polymer.bu.edu/~fding/sedawk/ch09_01.htm) to see what you need.

The big problem is finding the nearest match. Write an awk script that takes a single line of file 1 and outputs the lines in file 2 with an extra column. That column is the calculation of the distance between the pair of points according to your distance formula. If you sort that file numerically (`sort -n`) then your closest match is at the top. Then you need a script that loops over each line in file 1, calls your awk script, uses `head -n1` to pull out the closest match and then output it in the format that you want.

This is all possible in bash and awk, but it would be a much simpler script in Python. Depends on which you prefer.